# SpringBoot JACKSON configuration for JSON nested objects received by Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I have created Spring Boot app, in this app I have

```
@RestController
public class OfferController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/saveOffer", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void saveOffer(@RequestBody Offer offer) {
    //...
    }
}
```

Offer class contain nested property of Address type

```
public class Offer {

   private String title;
   private Address address;

   //... getters setters etc
}
```

When I'm sending `JSON` from UI

```
{
  "offer": {
    "title":"TheBestOffer",
    "address": {
      "city": "Warsaw"
    }
  }
}
```

My REST controller receives Offer, Address property is null but `title` property contains value `"TheBestOffer"` (as it was sended).

As I assume JACKSON delivered with Spring boot require some extra configuration for nested objects? I have tried to do this but it didn't work :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring does this automatically, i think your problem is with the json.

You need to remove offer tag.

```
{
    "title":"TheBestOffer",
    "address": {
      "city": "Warsaw"
    }
}
```

Comment: But why it fill title property?

Comment: I'm not sure why is setting the title property (I did some test and not set the value), but this is the correct way of send a request body.

Comment: What if a use case wants us to have the offer wrapper in request json as well. How can we handle that ?